# pg_ctl is not found after install postgresql12-server from pgdg repository in CentOS 8

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, centos, environment

I've recently installed PostgreSQL 12 through PostgreSQL official repositories (not CentOS). (https://yum.postgresql.org/12/redhat/rhel-8-x86_64)

However, `pg_ctl` command is not found after the setup process.

I've I do:

```
rpm -ql postgresql12-server |grep pg_ctl
/usr/pgsql-12/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/pgsql-12/share/man/man1/pg_ctl.1
```

It is not loaded pgsql-12 directory in PATH  environment variable. I've got a looking inside `/etc/profile.d/` I got this:

```
ls /etc/profile.d/
colorgrep.csh  colorxzgrep.csh  colorzgrep.csh  csh.local  gawk.sh   lang.sh   less.sh
colorgrep.sh   colorxzgrep.sh   colorzgrep.sh   gawk.csh   lang.csh  less.csh  sh.local
```

So... I didn't found any files named or referenced to pgsql.

I perform:

```
grep -rlio pgsql /etc/profile.d/
```

I didn't get anything... so, I understand why is not located pg_ctl by Bash.

`postgres` user cannot find it too. (I thought that's got a .bash_profile with PATH inside but It's not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to solve this?

- Create a file in `/etc/profile.d/pgsql.sh`
- Add the follows lines and save the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=${PATH}:/usr/pgsql-12/bin
export PATH
```

- Run this to update current PATH:

```
source /etc/profile.d/pgsql.sh
```

- Check the PATH now:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/pgsql-12/bin
```

- Run `pg_ctl --help`:

```
pg_ctl is a utility to initialize, start, stop, or control a PostgreSQL server.

Usage:
[...]
```

That's all!